# Eclipse IDE to AWS - Editor will not connect

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services

I am able to connect to my database, so credentials are working.

I cannot get the editor to connect, here is my error message.

Could anyone help please, I don't fully understand what the error message means.

```
Unable to open the server editor: Unsupported solution stack: 64bit Amazon 
Linux 2018.03 v2.8.1 running PHP 7.2
Unsupported solution stack: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.8.1 running PHP 7.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looking at the source code for this tool](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-eclipse/blob/master/bundles/com.amazonaws.eclipse.elasticbeanstalk/src/com/amazonaws/eclipse/elasticbeanstalk/solutionstacks/SolutionStacks.java#L38-L49), this error message is thrown if your solution stack isn't running Tomcat 6, 7, or 8.

Comment: Thanks. I gave up with Eclipse, it's so buggy. I just used NetBeans and FTP as I have been for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The issue was that I selected Java as the platform when creating a new environment.

I created another one with Tomcat as the environment and Eclipse now connects with no problem.

[image]